# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (1024) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model, seq2seq

I am doing the following operation,

```
energy.masked_fill(mask == 0, float("-1e20"))
```

my python traces are below,

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "seq_sum.py", line 418, in forward
    enc_src = self.encoder(src, src_mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "seq_sum.py", line 71, in forward
    src = layer(src, src_mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "seq_sum.py", line 110, in forward
    _src, _ = self.self_attention(src, src, src, src_mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "seq_sum.py", line 191, in forward
    energy =  energy.masked_fill(mask == 0, float("-1e20"))
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (1024) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 3
```

These are my attention layers code,

```
    Q = self.fc_q(query)
    K = self.fc_k(key)
    V = self.fc_v(value)
    
    #Q = [batch size, query len, hid dim]
    #K = [batch size, key len, hid dim]
    #V = [batch size, value len, hid dim]
            
    # Q = Q.view(batch_size, -1, self.n_heads, self.head_dim).permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
    # K = K.view(batch_size, -1, self.n_heads, self.head_dim).permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
    # V = V.view(batch_size, -1, self.n_heads, self.head_dim).permute(0, 2, 1, 3)

    Q = Q.view(batch_size, -1, self.n_heads, self.head_dim).view(-1, 1024)
    K = K.view(batch_size, -1, self.n_heads, self.head_dim).view(-1, 1024)
    V = V.view(batch_size, -1, self.n_heads, self.head_dim).view(-1, 1024)
    energy = torch.matmul(Q, K.transpose(1,0)) / self.scale
```

I am following below github code to do my seq to seq operation,[seq2seq pytorch](https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-seq2seq/blob/master/6%20-%20Attention%20is%20All%20You%20Need.ipynb)
actual testing code is available on the below location, [code to test a seq of 1024 to 1024 output](https://github.com/VinACE/trans-vsumm/blob/master/seq_sum.py)

[2nd example tried](https://github.com/VinACE/trans-vsumm/blob/master/vasnet_seq2seq_summ.py) here I have commented out pos_embedding due CUDA error with large index ([RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59)](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/97/498151254)

Comment: can you share the piece of code where you define `mask`?

Comment: import torch.nn as nn nn.LayerNorm(feature_size)

Comment: @skinny_func    please find some code references with some more example, code references are there in the below link, https://github.com/VinACE/trans-vsumm/blob/master/vasnet_seq2seq_summ.py

Comment: example code, https://github.com/VinACE/trans-vsumm/blob/master/vasnet_seq2seq_summ.py

Comment: @skinny_func did you get some time to test the above-mentioned code(s) https://github.com/VinACE/trans-vsumm/blob/master/vasnet_seq2seq_summ.py

Comment: did you run everything as is or have you changed something?

Comment: It just looks like when you are creating the mask it is of size 1024 whereas the energy is 512

Comment: @skinny_func  could you please run the reference link(https://github.com/vinace/trans-vsumm/blob/master/vasnet_seq2seq_summ_v2.py), you are right the energy and the mask sizes are different, I wanted to understand why this behaviour when I changed the input feature set, for an input feature of 10 it works, when I changed it to 1024 it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look at your code (which by the way, didnt run with `seq_len = 10`) and the problem is that you hard coded the `batch_size` to be equal 1 (line `143`) in your code.

It looks like the example you are trying to run the model on has `batch_size = 2`.

Just uncomment the previous line where you wrote `batch_size = query.shape[0]` and everything runs fine.

Comment: let me check that

Comment: yes the example after commenting the batch size work, thank you,